# Is there some problem using pnpm with github packages?

Tags: pnpm

My `~/.npmrc` looks like

```
% cat ~/.npmrc
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=XXXXXXX
//npmjs.org=true
@1uphealth:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/1uphealth
```

In theory our packages like `@1uphealth/foobar` get installed from our private `github packages` repository and this works fine for `npm`

It seems to match the pnpm docs, here, https://pnpm.io/npmrc#url_authtoken, too.

But I am getting this error,

```
 ERR_PNPM_FETCH_401  GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/1uphealth/@1uphealth%2Fcore-1upenv-script: Unauthorized - 401

No authorization header was set for the request.

These authorization settings were found:
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=[hidden]
@1uphealth:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/1uphealth
```

Comment: Doh!  https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/2933